# Folium GeoJson not displaying fill color correctly

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I'm working on a project where I need to display GeoJSON data using Folium in Python. I'm facing an issue with the fill color not displaying correctly.

I'm using the following code:

```
import folium
import requests
import json

# Load GeoJSON data from the provided URL
url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/product/shakemap/us7000kufc/us/1699242609676/download/cont_mmi.json"
response = requests.get(url)
geojson_data = json.loads(response.text)

# Create a folium map centered around the first coordinate in the GeoJSON
mymap = folium.Map(location=[geojson_data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0][1],
                              geojson_data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0][0]],
                   zoom_start=10)

# Define colors based on the "value" property
colors = ['#a0e5ff', '#90f2ff', '#80ffff', '#80dfff', '#80bfff', '#809fff', '#8080ff', '#bf80ff', '#df80ff', '#ff80ff']

# Add GeoJSON layer to the map with different colors
folium.GeoJson(
    geojson_data,
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        'fillColor': colors[int(feature['properties']['value'])],
        'color': colors[int(feature['properties']['value'])],
        'weight': 3,
        'fillOpacity': 0.5,  # Adjust opacity value
        'closed': True  # Close the polygons
    }
).add_to(mymap)

# Display the map
mymap
```

The issue is that while the contour color is displaying correctly, the fill color is not visible. I have experimented with different values for fillOpacity, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem, and how can I make the fill color visible?

[image]

Comment: The type of geojson you are using is MultiLineString, so it will not be filled unless it is a polygon. `geojson_data['features'][0];{'type': 'Feature',
 'properties': {'value': 3.0, 'units': 'mmi', 'color': '#a0e5ff', 'weight': 2},
 'geometry': {'type': 'MultiLineString',...`

Comment: is it possible to create polygons with these lines, with the bbox?

Comment: Probably not possible, I would need a geometry data structure.